Stop packaging application-local properties in Docker image
I have a Spring Boot application that includes several application-XXX.properties profiles. When I build Docker image using jib, I notice that all these properties files are packaged in the image in /app/resouces.
Is there a way to only include the main application.properties and prevent including the specific properties for various profiles in the Docker image? This could potentially leak some sensitive details if left there.
Is this some jib gradle configuration?

Don't include them in the folders packed to the JAR file. I suggest the following structure:
app
│
├── pom.xml
├── ext
│   └── application-localhost.properties
└── src
    ├── main
    │   ├── java
    │   │   └── ...
    │   └── resources
    │       └── application.properties
    └── test
        ├── java
        │   └── ...
        └── resources
            └── ...


src/main/resources are the resources packed and delivered with the JAR.
ext are the resources specific to each environment (ex. localhost)

if you run the application locally, mark the ext directory as the resources for the local build.
if you run the application on the environment, ex. a Docker container in K8S, mount the external properties as config-map.




Thank you, that makes sense to me. Probably better way than specifying custom exclude in gradle build file.

By any chance, is it possible to configure gradle to mark the ext directory as local resource toot automatically without having to do it manually after each git clone?

I am sorry, I am not a Gradle user. Can't help. I hope someone else would post a better answer.

I just realized that these properties are not picked during startup even when I mark them manually, probably missing some config somewhere
